# Discrete color scale for plotly graph object

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to plot a choropleth map with discrete colorbar (including the label), like this picture

[image]

But all I have found so far is doing this using plotly express. I have to use plotly graph objects because I have multiple traces containing different types of plots. So is there any `color_discrete_sequence` equivalence for plotly graph objects? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71104827/plotly-express-choropleth-map-custom-color-continuous-scale) may be helpful.

Comment: your need to use graph objects does not preclude using plotly express... you can use **px** to create traces and integrate them using **go**.  the answer I provided that is linked by @r-beginners is generic in this respect.  update question with what you have tried using this approach if you cannot get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using same solution [custom color_continuous_scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71104827/plotly-express-choropleth-map-custom-color-continuous-scale) but making MWE work with generally available geometry
- I did find one subtle issue, `pd.cut()` can return negative edges when all values are positive.  This will cause **plotly** to fail.  Have floored minimum edge to zero
- I'd always go with using **px**. Have also provided **go**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# sample data
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

edges = pd.cut(gdf["gdp_md_est"], bins=5, retbins=True)[1]
edges = edges[:-1] / edges[-1]
# color scales don't like negative edges...
edges = np.maximum(edges, np.full(len(edges), 0))
colors = ["#e5e5e5", "#ffe5f0", "#facfdf", "#f3b8ce", "#eca2bf", "#e37fb1"]

cc_scale = (
    [(0, colors[0])]
    + [(e, colors[(i + 1) // 2]) for i, e in enumerate(np.repeat(edges, 2))]
    + [(1, colors[5])]
)

fig = px.choropleth(
    gdf,
    geojson=gdf.__geo_interface__,
    locations=gdf.index,
    hover_data=["iso_a3","name"],
    color="gdp_md_est",
    color_continuous_scale=cc_scale,
)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
```

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

go.Figure(
    go.Choropleth(
        geojson=gdf.__geo_interface__,
        locations=gdf.index,
        z=gdf["gdp_md_est"],
        coloraxis="coloraxis",
    )
).update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False).update_layout(
    coloraxis={"colorscale": cc_scale}
)
```

#### output - discrete color bins

[image]