# How to make a discrete colorbar for plotly.graph_objects.Heatmap?

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I want to visualize [this](https://pastebin.com/HdyujvXw) spatio-temporal data in a Plotly heatmap. A working example that includes [this](https://pastebin.com/HdyujvXw) data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d) # use the data dict here
n_locations = df.location_encoded.nunique()
pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index='day', columns='time', values='location_encoded', aggfunc='first')

heatmap_data = pivot_table.values

x_labels = pivot_table.columns
y_labels = pivot_table.index

cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis', n_locations)

color_map = [cmap(i) for i in range(n_locations)]

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
    z=heatmap_data,
    x=x_labels,
    y=y_labels,
    colorscale=[[i / (n_locations - 1), f"rgba{color_map[i]}"] for i in range(n_locations)],
    colorbar=dict(
        tickvals=np.arange(n_locations),
        title='Location'
    ),
))

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(title='Time of Day'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Date'),
    title='Heatmap of Location Data',
)

fig.show()
```

This produces the following heatmap:
[image]

The colorbar on the right is now a continuous scale, but I want it to be a discrete scale, i.e., all locations have their own color. [Examples on Plotly's website](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#constructing-a-discrete-or-discontinuous-color-scale) show the usage of `color_continuous_scale`, however, this parameter is only available for `plotly.express` visuals. How can the colorbar be made discrete for a `go.Heatmap`?

**UPDATE:**
The following code seems to work perfectly (thanks to the comments):

```
# First we create a list of np.linspace values where each value repeats twice, except for the beginning (0) and the ending (1)
vals = np.r_[np.array(0), np.repeat(list(np.linspace(0, 1, self.n_locations+1))[1:-1], 2), np.array(1)]

# Then we make a list that contains lists of the values and the corresponding colors.
cc_scale = [[j, colors[i//2]] for i, j in enumerate(vals)]

# Create the heatmap using Plotly
self.fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
    z=self.heatmap_data,
    x=x_labels,
    y=y_labels,
    colorscale=cc_scale,
    colorbar=dict(
        tickvals=np.linspace(1/self.n_locations/2, 1 - 1/self.n_locations/2, self.n_locations) * (self.n_locations - 1), # Center the ticks 
        ticktext=self.location_labels,
        title='Location'
    ),
))
```

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73603595/discrete-color-scale-for-plotly-graph-object) to be very helpful

Comment: @r-beginners thanks for the link. I don't really see how their example is different from my code, as we both define a similar colorscale. Could you explain what exactly in their example defines the discrete colorbar?

Comment: My understanding is that it is the same technique as the examples in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#custom-discretized-heatmap-color-scale-with-graph-objects). `location_encoded` to a normalized value.

Comment: Let say `n_locations=2`, your code would produce something like `[(0, 'red'), (1, 'blue')]`, which tells plotly to create a continuous colorscale ranging from 0-red to 1-blue. You need to be explicitly about the boundaries, eg. `[(0, 'red'), (0.5, 'red'), (0.5, 'blue'), (1, 'blue')]`, which is a bit verbose but required to get a discrete color scale. Basically you could do : `colorscale=[(
(i+j) / n_locations, f"rgba{cmap(i)}" )
for i in range(n_locations)
for j in range(2)]`.

Comment: @EricLavault What you are describing is indeed the solution. I updated the OP. Thanks for helping out!